# Low Quality Post audit failed

Tags: support, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

The Low Quality Post queue has been something that I find hard to understand. The name is very suggestive, the options you see when you mark something are very suggestive, but reading on meta I get the feeling something else is required.

I saw the red dot this morning and opened the queue and my first thought was "Let's check on meta what they really want from me". So I read [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/434949), and didn't skim it, but still I failed an audit on the second [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17386976) and I have no idea why.

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please delete or recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

The question boils down to "How can I find newly registered domains for .com and .net", and the answers says "There are services that provide them and you can find one here *url*"

How is that a low quality answer? Having asked a similar question a few weeks ago, I would have been happy with this answer and probably marked it as the solution.

Comment: Just always assume that whomever flagged the post had a very good reason to do so.  And that, If you are going to override his concern, then you need a very good reason to do so.  In this case, at a *minimum* you need to check what is fishy about that URL.  And in general you need to look at the rest of the answers to the question to see if you are not killing off the only half-decent answer and perhaps need to post a comment to urge the poster to improve his answer.  At which point you can never fail an audit like this since you'll notice that the post isn't there anymore.

Comment: I spotted the [next spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17390423) successfully thanks to you guys. I feel like a better person already.

Comment: The question is off topic... I wonder why the meta effect hasn't hit yet?

Comment: The question is marked on hold now, so it attracted enough close votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's spam.

It's not written as an answer: *"I do this, I do that, all using [link]"*.
It's a typical "success story" advertisement of some kind of library or API.

If it were written as an answer, it would've been more like:
*"You can use [link] to do X and Y"*,
but then that would imply the question was only a resource request, which would probably have to be closed any way.
Looking at the question again, that appears to be the case.

Comment: Sure, the question might not be suited for the site, but does that qualify all answers as low quality when they answer it? I never knew that making an answer a bit more personal with "I use this option" when there are several options available, instantly made it spam.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't look like it's written for this specific question. There's no reference to anything the OP says. It's all _"I use this, you should too."_

Comment: Did you take other things in consideration to get to that conclusion? Like a new user or posted many years later, or purely bases on the answer? Because I seriously don't understand why it's so obviously spam to you. Sure, it could be better worded, but it does provide a solution and the user even asked for payed services

Comment: Ps: I'm not trying to be annoying or right, but want to learn to prevent mistakes in the future.

Comment: We don't know how new the user was when he posted it. For me, it's just a certain manner of recognition...

Comment: @HugoDelsing - I handled the flags on this user and can provide a little more context. A new user had left four posts, all promoting this service, their profile consisted of a glowing endorsement of this service, and it was very obvious from their login info that they were one of the principals of it. Their posts were flagged as spam and destroyed by myself and other members of the community (I believe it was picked up by the Smoke Detector bot), and I trashed their account. You didn't have that context, but when the spam flag was validated and the post deleted it became an audit case.

Comment: In general, be very suspicious of new posts to old questions by new users that advocate the use of a commercial product or service and talk about it in glowing terms. That's something to be on the lookout for in Low Quality Post review. When in doubt, check out the user account (which in this case would have taken you to a missing profile, showing that they had been deleted).

Comment: In defense of Hugo, I agree that it is difficult as a Low Quality Post reviewer to be able to see hidden context about a user's activities on the site on other posts. Perhaps a post like this marked as spam shouldn't be used as an audit question.

Comment: @Kirby if you have a proposal to exclude spam flagged posts for audit, please post it as a new question.

Answer (score -4):

As you indicated, the answer says **There are services that provide them and you can find one here *{{url}}***

That may be a spam. Spam posts are posts that are used to promote existing product or service. Here the person who made the answer may did the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer doesn't make any sense to me: _That should be spam if the url links to some profitable organization._ -> So, all links to products from Google, Microsoft, Oracle, etc are spam, since they are profitable organization ?! _Spam posts are posts that are used to promote existing product or service._ So, a non-spam post should promote unexisting products ?!

Comment: does all answers on SO is promoting non-existing products? what do you think @Adinia

Comment: As far as I know, they don't :) That's exactly why I asked you, as deducing from your definition, you seem to be implying those are the only accepted ones.