# Review open votes audit feel like boobytraps

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-reopen

Yesterday I [failed an audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356795/434949) for the *low quality post* queue and asked about it here. Hans Passant gave a very nice comment, which I'm trying to follow in the queues now:

> Just always assume that whoever flagged the post had a very good reason to do so. And that, If you are going to override his concern, then you need a very good reason to do so.

Sounds like solid advice, but if I follow it in the *Review open votes* queue I always feel tricked by the audits. This [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17399966) was closed with the reason *it's primarily opinion based*.

Hardly any edit (if any at all) were visible in the post and it ends with:

> What is the best practice in this case?

I do see that the question is well formatted and it feels right, but considering the close reason and the last question, I clicked *leave close* because nothing was changed and it asks for an opinion in the end. **Fail!**

Now I don't mind failing if I do something wrong, but this just feels like a trap. The audit for this queue I failed yesterday, had the same scenario. My first thought was: "I'll just leave that queue alone, because this sucks", but considering it's the second largest queue, I wonder if more people feel like this and skip it because of it?

Comment: Difficult one. Spring Boot is driven by conventions so it is actually rather easy to answer requests for "best practices" - the best practice is to follow the documented conventions which the answer given there sort of does, but it is worded in a rather opinionated way. I see how people would want to cast 'opinionated' close votes and I see how people would want to cast reopen votes. In other words: it sucks as an audit target.

Comment: The post has a trigger phrase, "best practice".  If you review it then you basically only need to determine if replacing it with "correct" or "appropriate" would stop making it opinion-based.  Not really, no compelling reason to override the decision from 5 users that know spring well.  If they had actually done that, but they didn't.  They in fact really liked it.  This is another audit that is easy to pass.  Not actually closed, 3 weeks old, 25 helpful votes, no down or close votes => audit.  You have to look, what the machine checks for.  Skip is a good choice.

Comment: well I have a userscript to detect audits.

Comment: @i-- the fact that you would need that, is a sign that either the audits are broken, or you're not reviewing properly and want to continue doing so. The audits (at least for other review queues) are meant to test that you're paying attention, and know something about reviewing. They're not meant to be trick questions you spend a lot of time on (at least, that's what I believe and have read elsewhere). If users want to bypass them, that's a sign of bad audits to me.

Comment: Actually I figured this was an audit, because it was very similar to the one yesterday. I actually thought I was making the right call. I didn't know I was supposed to cheat the audits by simply clicking the title of the post to see the actual page. The audits are usually easy to spot if you had a few, but if the goal is to find ways to bypass them, then just don't use them at all.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth in some situations, you can't be 100% sure what action you have to take. If that audit is an open question from 2k09 or 2k10, there are many unsalvagable questions which is still open. So YOU WILL FAIL that audit. in such case, a userscript is helpful for me. still I failed some reviews because not using the user script(clicking the button) and got a review ban once. So don't judge whether I'm reviewing properly or not

Comment: @i-- I'm not judging you, I'm just saying that the fact you made this proves that audits are broken. For myself, I did the thing that OP thought, I got 2 audits wrong, and didn't visit the queue again for weeks, and it's still the queue I visit the least

Comment: There is a misconception that an audit checks whether you review correctly.  Not what they do, audits were deemed necessary because there was a problem with users not spending enough time on review.  Racing through a queue at a 6 seconds per review clip was a common issue.  It still is.  So audits only check if you pay enough attention, the machine likes to pick the kind of question where that is most easily testable.  Like this one, flagged but yet highly appreciated by the tag community.  There is a boobytrap, the review page gives a less than stellar view of the Q+A.  Easy to fix.

Comment: I also thought the audits were to check quality. But then it's clear what to do. Thanks.

Comment: @HugoDelsing its more to maintain quality. For good or bad reasons its only too easy that people start to burn through reviews way too quickly and make all the wrong decisions as a result of it. This can be especially true when there are lots of items to review and people start to roll up their sleeves to fix that situation, so to speak. It sucks if you get suckered into an audit when you're still taking your time, but if you see reviewing as a game: you have the most fun playing when you learn to laugh away unfair losses.

Comment: Bad audits are like plane crashes. You don't hear about every successful plane landing, only the crashes. So when you see a rise in plane crashes you automatically assume there's a problem. It isn't that all of the pilots suddenly forgot how to fly, it is the fact that there are more planes in the sky.

Comment: The bottom line is that it is often risky to attempt a review without looking at the original context. This is especially true if you don't know the topic of the question particularly well. There is a link (top-right of the page) that should open the original question in a new tab. Always click on that *first* and do a quick scan of the page before looking in detail at the question itself. You will very rarely fail an audit if you do things that way.

Comment: Suggested title change: "Review o̶p̶e̶n̶ ̶v̶o̶t̶e̶s audits feel like boobytraps"

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Audits are broken, imo. They make the system more frustrating for people who do care about reviewing properly. I dunno what the answer is, but audits are a pain in the rear.

Comment: I'd still prefer a "I disagree, your test was wrong" button. As I simply refuse to click the "I understand" button ... unless that button is changed to "I understand this audit system is a flawed piece of crap".

Answer (score 1):

"*Just always assume that whomever flagged the post had a very good reason to do so*" is good advice.  And it applies to reopen votes, too.

If you see a question in the reopen votes review queue (and it's not there just due to being edited while closed), you should assume that at least one other user looked at the question and thought "Hmm, that question *really* shouldn't be closed.  Let me vote to reopen it."*

Of course, you might legitimately disagree.  It's quite possible that whoever voted to reopen that post was simple wrong, or out of touch with community consensus on what kinds of questions should be kept closed.  I know for sure [I've had that happen to me.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/is-this-question-really-too-broad-and-if-so-how-did-i-manage-to-answer-it-anyw)  But before voting against them, you should at least try to understand *why* they though the question deserved to be reopened.

If there's no obvious reason visible in the review interface, it's often a good idea to open the actual question page in a new tab and take a closer look at it.  Some things you may want to check are:

- any answers the question might already have,
- the comments on those answers, and
- the question edit history.

A somewhat hidden, but also occasionally useful, additional source of information is the [question timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262678/why-is-there-no-link-to-timeline-of-the-post), which gives you an overview of when the question was closed and what has happened to it since then.

Of course, as a side effect, opening the question in a new tab will also easily reveal audits.  Which is exactly what audits are supposed to achieve: make you pay extra attention to non-obvious cases in review.

If, after taking a closer look at the question, you *still* can't figure out why someone might have wanted to see it reopened, consider leaving a comment on the question saying so before clicking the "Leave Closed" button.  It's possible that whoever originally voted to reopen the question might read it (since they presumably had some reason to visit the question in the first place) and actually explain their reasoning.  And even if not, at least it's a helpful note to other reviewers.

Finally, if all this seems like way too much hard work, there's always another option: just "Skip" it.  Seriously, if you don't feel like spending a lot of time reviewing complex or borderline cases, it's perfectly fine to just skip those and only handle the easy and obvious stuff.  That way, other reviewers who *do* want to take the time to look more closely into the non-trivial cases won't have to wade through so much boring and trivial stuff to get to them.

<sup>*) An extra complication in the reopen queue is that questions that are edited after being closed get automatically added to the queue.  IME, at least 90% of the time, those edits are completely superficial and/or misguided and do nothing to address the reason why the question was closed.  Which IMO makes that feature rather dubious, since its main effect seems to be to train reviewers to just always click "Leave Closed".  Fortunately it's at least easy enough to tell these automatic reopen reviews from actual reopen votes cast by actual users with reopen privileges.</sup>